# R Services on SQL continuously running in the background

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I am able to connect R Services to a SQL Server using a Compute Context (see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/sql-server-r-services)

Using this connection, I can run R commands on my SQL Server (awesome!), but for some reason as soon as I connect R to SQL server, the `Microsoft R Communication Component for SQL Server` continuously maxes out one of our cores (out of 8).  So, as soon as I make the connection, our CPU bumps up to 13% (1/8) and stays there.

I can close my R session and there are no queries or functions processing anymore, but nothing stops it from running `Microsoft R Communication Component for SQL Server` in the background until we bounce our server.

How do you **turn off** R Services in SQL?  How can you close the connection so that we're not continuously maxing out one of our cores even when NO PROCESSES are running and all R sessions are closed?

Comment: cpu 13% is normal .Are you facing any issue with `So, as soon as I make the connection, our CPU bumps up to 13% (1/8) and stays there`,

Comment: This server is mostly inactive unless we're running a job on it.  Our "normal" baseline was established over the past few months before we started using R Services, when the CPU rested around 0% unless we were running a SQL Query or a job on that server.  Now, once we connect to R Services, it continuously maxes out a core even when absolutely nothing is running and we have no way to "turn off" this connection without bouncing the server.  No one has done anything with R Services in days, yet our SQL Server is stuck at 13% CPU forever.